# Error While executing pig script which is saved in HDFS path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

1. I have placed .pig file and txt file in HDFS path
2. Trying to execute .pig from Grunt

getting below error

```
students.txt

001,Rajiv,Hyderabad
002,siddarth,Kolkata
003,Rajesh,Delhi

Script.pig 

student = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:8020/pig_data/students.txt' USING PigStorage(',') 
   as (id:int,name:chararray,city:chararray);

Dump student;

grunt> exec /user/cloudera/pig_data/script.pig


2019-07-24 12:13:35,303 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2019-07-24 12:13:35,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2019-07-24 12:13:35,376 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2019-07-24 12:13:35,378 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2019-07-24 12:13:35,384 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. File not found: /user/cloudera/pig_data/script.pig
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1563995548146.log
grunt>
```

Comment: Where have you found a reference that you should be able to exec a remote HDFS pig script?

Comment: I found similar example from tutorial point ,  can you please help how to fix this issue

Comment: I think the solution is to not use a script on HDFS...

Comment: The official docs say nothing about it http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/cmds.html#exec